# How do I get migration seed data for a default user with pw and role, which works locally to work when I publish it to Azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-sql-database

I have an MVC 4 EF web project with a code-first sql server db that very closely follows the basic and usual structure of any you would see as an example anywhere on the web.

I have read EVERY article posted on the internet concerning how to do what I need and none of them so far make any difference to my situation. I am not doing anything extraordinary, I just took out the 'Register' new user capability as needed by my project, and am trying to create a couple of users as login points by including them in the Migrations/Configuration.cs file like this:

```
    protected override void Seed (EntityContext context)
    {
        if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

        if (!Roles.RoleExists("Administrator"))
            Roles.CreateRole("Administrator");

        if (!WebSecurity.UserExists("Owner"))
            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("Owner", "password");

        if (!Roles.GetRolesForUser("Owner").Contains("Administrator"))
            Roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { "Owner" }, new[] { "Administrator" });

        if (!WebSecurity.UserExists("fred"))
            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("leemid", "pw");
        if (!Roles.GetRolesForUser("leemid").Contains("Administrator"))
            Roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { "leemid" }, new[] { "Administrator" });

        base.Seed(context);
    }
```

Everything works beautifully locally, but when I publish to my Azure account, where everything is set up properly as near as I can tell, the app appears correctly except that I can't login as my seeded user. I have connected to my Azure db using SQL Management Studio and all of the UserProfile and webpages_ tables are there, the app specific ones are not because the code-first hasn't had a chance to build the yet (I assume), but there are no users or roles. Locally, everything is built and populated as expected.

I have added the often suggested code in the root Web.config file thus:

```
<system.web>
  <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
      <providers>
          <clear/>
          <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
      </providers>
  </roleManager>
  <membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
          <clear/>
          <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider"
               type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
      </providers>
  </membership>
```

It certainly took all of this to accomplish successful publishing of the site, but I am frustrated by the lack of success in seeding the users. Any one solved this already?